# Create newlines at the first of multiple similar variables or end of set

Tags: bash, command-line, text-formatting

I can't seem to get a regex that won't put a newline between all `domain:` occurrences or only between `domain:` and `dataamount:`

I've tried to contract the section's newlines into commas thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines) helpful post on askubuntu so that I can work with the resulting fields, but it seems to be fruitless.

`| grep -e ' domain:' -e 'total'  | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,dataamount:/,\ndataamount:/g' | tr , '\n'`

It will just add a newline between the last `domain:` and `dataamount:` when I'd like it after `dataamount: [0-9].*\'?`

```
    domain: domain1.com
    domain: domain2.info
    domain: domain3.com
dataamount: 9210470
    domain: domain4.com
    domain: domain5.com
    domain: domain6.com
dataamount: '25325235235'
    domain: domain7.com
    domain: domain8.com
dataamount: 12321
```

I want to make the start of these sets of data have newlines.

```
    domain: domain1.com
    domain: domain2.info
    domain: domain3.com
dataamount: 9210470

    domain: domain4.com
    domain: domain5.com
    domain: domain6.com
dataamount: '25325235235'

    domain: domain7.com
    domain: domain8.com
dataamount: 12321
```

They all start with `domain:` and it seems that everywhere that lists awk/sed solutions to these problems doesn't account for both numbers and numbers in singlequotes being split to newlines AND keeps the numbers AND  will only match the starting `domain:` until after a set so it's hard to find anything that will match my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you want to add newlines after `dataamount`. You need to `group` the entire `dataamount` line and append a newline. It can done with sed using `s/^(dataamount.*)/\1\n/g`.

The regex `^(dataamount.*)` searches lines starting with `dataamount` due to `^`. Because we use `()`, we group it and it becomes usable as `\1` in the replacement part. This `\1` is called a backreference, which is part of extended regex. After the reference, which is the entire line, we add a newline `\n`.

```
$ sed -r 's/^(dataamount.*)/\1\n/g' file.txt 
    domain: domain1.com
    domain: domain2.info
    domain: domain3.com
dataamount: 9210470

    domain: domain4.com
    domain: domain5.com
    domain: domain6.com
dataamount: '25325235235'

    domain: domain7.com
    domain: domain8.com
dataamount: 12321
```

You could've gotten this from my previous nudge:

```
perl -pe 's#^\s+domain: (.*)\n$#\1, #;s#(dataamount.*)$#\n\1#' file.txt
```

The latter regex, `s#(dataamount.*)$#\n\1#`, did just that ;-)

Comment: You're right, it is unclear on what I want. I've added clarity above.